# How Do I Hide an LVM Physical Volume from the Devices Section on the Nautilus Side Pane?

Tags: nautilus, mount, encryption

I installed 12.04 on my netbook with the Alternate CD ISO. I have set up 3 partitions and encrypted them with **dm_crypt**.

When I boot up, I enter a pass phrase for each partition and they are all accessible after I log in, but they show up under the Devices pane in Nautilus.

How can I prevent them from showing up? I have them in `fstab` as `/dev/mapper`.

Answer (score 2):

If you edit your `/etc/fstab` file and change the mounting point to somewhere outside `/media` (eg. `/mnt`), the logical volume(s) won't show on the Nautilus Side Pane.